# How to make changes in server of a struts project

Tags: java, struts

Im basically a php programmer and eventually i had to work on a java project. The java project is done with struts framework and we have given the task to change the listing of result based on "X". When i set the project in my local system and made changes on java file say abc.java and build the new class. The changes worked fine on my local system. But when i replaced the abc.class file with the new build class in the server, its not working. Any assistance in this issue will be appreciated.

I set appache tomcat 7.0 in my local system.
And used net beans 7.0 IDE to build the new class files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your change will probably be visible when you restart your webserver.

What you should do is automate your build: 
You should use ant or maven to create a war file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_(Sun) and let your script upload this war file to your local server / production server. The server will automatically detect a new webapp version and deploy it.

Ideally, your deployment task should perform a checkout from your versioning system (git, cvs, svn), perform the needed unit test, integration tests, etc.  Only when all tests are passed, can the webapp be deployed on your server.